# RSS and Post edits

Tags: rss

I have a blog with "dynamic content" (one type of post data is changing (the date, too) based on some circumstances). If I give the feed to one RSS feeder and one chatfuel based chatbot will the changes also "shown" (for example if a post was published in 2th of January and today the date was changed to 15th of January) will it move in the post order in the RSS feeds, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should since the RSS feed is based on the current instance of `WP_Query`. However by default WordPress has a longer interval for updating the RSS feed's cache. IIRC, it's about 12 hours. So if you make a change at 6am, the RSS feed won't reflect that until 6pm.

You can change this with the following code in your `functions.php` file or, even better, as a plugin.

```
function rss_update_feed() {
    return 60;  //Time in seconds
}
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 'rss_update_feed' );
```

What this code does is sets the refresh time to 60 seconds. You will want to set it to something a bit more reasonable though. I only used 60 seconds as an example but you do not want to have your server keep doing unnecessary refreshes.

Comment: You're welcome. What interval did you end up using?

Comment: I made it to 5 minutes